# Peptide fragment software in mass spectrometry

Tags: bioinformatics, mass-spectrometry

I am trying to study peptide fragmentation in mass spectrometry.
My goal is to find software with which I can retrieve the molecular structure of the peptide and see the a,b,c fragments.

I found these two online tools.
[**Pep draw**](https://www2.tulane.edu/%7Ebiochem/WW/PepDraw/) & [**Fragment Ion Calculator**](http://db.systemsbiology.net:8080/proteomicsToolkit/FragIonServlet.html). Ι entered a short sequence and I retrieved the m/z values for the a.b.c and x.y.z values in a table.

Is there any software /online tool that I will add a peptide sequence and automatically generate the chemical structure? I want this image generated but for my peptide sequence instead of the side chains.

[image]

Comment: By "generate automatically the chemical structure" do you mean the 3-d structure of the fragment peptide? If you google "predicting 3d structure of peptides from sequence" you'll find references to a bunch of software that attempts to do this, the [PEP-Fold server](https://bioserv.rpbs.univ-paris-diderot.fr/services/PEP-FOLD/) for example. Of course as the fragment gets larger the problem gets harder, and you end up needing [Alpha-Fold](https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk).

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant I just edited my post. Maybe now is more clear what I am searching for.